# insert a text file into another text file after a string using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have two xml files. I need to add contents of one xml file say file1.xml into another say file2.xml after a specific tag.

file1.xml

```
<server>
    <id>6</id>
    <host_name>abd</host_name>
</server>
<server>
    <id>7</id>
    <host_name>abc</host_name>
</server>
```

file2.xml

```
<serverList>
   <server>
     <id>10</id>
    <host_name>bhgd</host_name>
</server>
<server>
    <id>19</id>
    <host_name>mngvd</host_name>
</server>
</serverList>
```

I need to insert file1.xml into file 2.xml before tag `</serverList>`

**Expected Result:**

```
<serverList>
       <server>
         <id>10</id>
        <host_name>bhgd</host_name>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>19</id>
        <host_name>mngvd</host_name>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>6</id>
        <host_name>abd</host_name>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>7</id>
        <host_name>abc</host_name>
    </server>
  </serverList>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't have a code so (you better to use xml parsers but if you don't):

```
with open("file1.xml", "r") as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()
with open("file2.xml","r") as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()
with open("file3.xml","a") as f3:
    for line in lines2:
        if line == "</serverList>"
            f3.write(lines1+"\n")
            f3.write(line+"\n")
        else:
            f3.write(line+"\n") 
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["mv file3.xml file2.xml"],shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is always to use xml parsers. Dom4j is a pretty good one look it up. For this piece of code you need dom4j and jaxen jars or maven dependencies.

```
Document xml1 = new SAXReader().read(new File("file1.xml"));
Document xml2 = new SAXReader().read(new File("file2.xml"));
List<Element> servers = (List<Element>) xml1.selectNodes("//*/server");
for(Element server : servers)
xml2.getRootElement().addElement(server);
```

And then save xml2 into a file